# Rails 3 ajax for :remote => true spinner on section of page not on whole page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, spinner

I need spinner on particular section of the page and not on whole page.

I am using form_for with remote => true, so it goes to the controller and then went to js.erb file and loads the partial .

I do not understand where do i set the spinner image in html should it be on application.html OR on the section on which i need spinner?

I do not understand where to write js should it be in js.erb file or in application.js file?

I have many section on the page and I need spinner button on ajax request but it should be on separate section and not on whole page.

Please help me.